# Is there a equal predefined variable like $_REQUEST in code-igniter?

Tags: php, post, get, request

The variables in `$_REQUEST` are provided to the script via the `GET`, `POST`, and `COOKIE` input mechanisms.

Is there a way in code igniter to access `GET` and `POST` both data through one predefined variable or function

Comment: @HamzaZafeer can I access data which receive as a GET method from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$this->input->post_get('some_data', TRUE);
```

This will work like `$_REQUEST`.More function are there like `cookie`,`server`.

For more information check [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)